# Bloom or some other post-processing (filter) on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webgl, post-processing

Is it possible to apply post-processing effects, such as bloom or chromatic aberration, over a whole web page? I know that we can write shaders for a canvas element, but would they take effect on whatever is rendered beneath said canvas element, if we stretched it over the whole page like a transparent overlay?

By the way, I don't think CSS filters are what I'm looking for, since I can't create my own.

Comment: I have the same question, my first taste of development was in Unity and I remember how useful post processing was. It seems natural to do the same in the browser.